# AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'is_floating'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I develop my own op using eager execution. I met an error. How to fix it?

> Env: Colaboratory TF ver.: 1.14

I use:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
```

I tried `tf.convert_to_tensor()` but it led to other error. Error caused by:

```py
loss_value, grads = grad(x_, y)
```

Error message:

```
    962     flat_sources = [_handle_or_self(x) for x in flat_sources]
    963     for t in flat_sources_raw:
--> 964       if not t.dtype.is_floating:
    965         logging.vlog(
    966             logging.WARN, "The dtype of the source tensor must be "

AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'is_floating'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got that reason of the error which indicates "if not is_floating" for the raising the exception.

To solve the error, it needs to make variable to a tensor, just using `convert_to_tensor()` before an operation.